# Atom editor text spacing

Tags: atom-editor

I am working on a project using my favorite text editor 'Atom' while working on a main.js file... I had noticed a little difference in the text spacing, it was not like i use to be.

The character spacing is to close together so are the parenthesis.

What could have caused this and how could this be fixed?

Current Settings:

**Font : 20px

Font-Family: Source Code Pro**

I've tried evertything to fix this but everything i've tried is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! ... This issue was fixed by changing the font family inside of atom